# Java regex to detect if statements - detecting comments

Tags: java, regex

I would like to count how many `if` statements are in code.

The problem is that: an `if` word can be inside(and it **should not** count as `if` statement) the comment and I have to detect if I am inside the
comment?

Can it be done using java's regex? How to detect `if` only outside the comment?

Comment: This shouldn't be done with regexes. Not only comments, but also string literals are your enemy.

Comment: @JanDvorak I try to make it now. I'll post effects in 20 minutes.

Comment: You are better off using something like parboiled; which incidentally has a Java source code parser

Comment: Something useful in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Write a loop, which reads line by line every step. If a single line comment `//` as first characters is found, skip the line. If a multiline `/*` or javadoc comment `/**` found, read in lines until the ending tags found.

But that's not all you have to think about. Use the above logic to skip strings `"blabla, if"` or what else an `if` can appear.